# Cannot see getElementById function in node properties (Web Inspector Safari)

Tags: javascript

As the title says I can't see this function. I'm afraid that there is more function that I can't see. Any of you guys has the same? Maybe I should use other browser for better DOM Inspector.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if you look at the title of what is open in the right column on your image, it will say Element. And getElementById belongs to [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) interface, and not to [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). All DOM interfaces [are here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Comment: Thanks m8. But do you know how can I select document?

Comment: You ask tricky questions mate, and I don't know why you need it, but here is my answer after some research: Type in browser console `console.dir(Document)`  to see the parent function that generate document object, click on output and go to prototype section, there you can find getElementById method. Type `console.dir(document)` to see the generated document object itself.